# How to report parsing errors when using JSON.parseFull with Scala

Tags: json, scala

When my app is fed syntactically incorrect JSON I want to be able to report the error to the user with some useful detail that will allow the problem area to be located.

So in this example j will be None because of the trailing comma after "File1". Is there a way to obtain details of last parse error?

```
    val badSyntax = """
{
  "menu1": {
    "id": "file1",
    "value": "File1",
  },
  "menu2": {
    "id": "file2",
    "value": "File2",
  }
}"""

    val j = JSON.parseFull(badSyntax)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a parse error, use `JSON.lastNoSuccess` to get the last error. It is of type `JSON.NoSuccess` of which thare are two subclasses, `JSON.Error` and `JSON.Failure`, both containing a `msg: String` member detailing the error.
Note that `JSON.lastNoSuccess` is not thread safe (it is a mere global variable) and is now deprecated (bound to disappear in scala 2.11)

**UPDATE**: Apparently, I was wrong about it not being thread-safe: it was indeed not thread-safe before scala 2.10, but now `lastNoSuccess` is backed by a thread-local variable (and is thus safe to use in a multi-threaded context). 
After seing this, you'd be forgiven to think that as long as you read right after a parsing failure **in the same thread as the one that was used to do the parsing** (the thread where you called `parseFull`), then everything will work as expected. Unfortunately, during this refactor they also changed how they use `lastNoSuccess` internally inside `Parsers.phrase` (which is called by `JSON.parseFull`. 
See https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/1a4faa92faaf495f75a6dd2c58376f6bb3fbf44c
Since this refactor, `lastNoSuccess` is reset to `None` at the end of `Parsers.phrase`. This is no problem in parsers in general, as `lastNoSuccess` is used as a temporary value that is returned as the result of `Parsers.phrase` anyway.
**The problem here is that we don't call `Parsers.phrase`, but `JSON.parseFull`, which drops any error info** (see `case None => None` inside method `JSON.parseRaw` at https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/util/parsing/json/JSON.scala).
The fact that `JSON.parseFull` drops any error info could easily be circumvented prior to scala 2.10 by directly reading `JSON.lastNoSuccess` as I advised before, but now that this value is reset at the end of `Parsers.phrase`, there is not much you can do to get the error information out of `JSON`.

**Any solution?** Yes. What you can do is to create your very own version of `JSON` that will not drop the error information:

```
import util.parsing.json._

object MyJSON extends Parser {
  def parseRaw(input : String) : Either[NoSuccess, JSONType] = {
    phrase(root)(new lexical.Scanner(input)) match {
      case Success(result, _) => Right(result)
      case ns: NoSuccess => Left(ns)
    }
  }

  def parseFull(input: String): Either[NoSuccess, Any] = {
    parseRaw(input).right.map(resolveType)
  }

  def resolveType(input: Any): Any = input match {
    case JSONObject(data) => data.transform {
      case (k,v) => resolveType(v)
    }
    case JSONArray(data) => data.map(resolveType)
    case x => x
  }
}
```

I just changed `Option` to `Either` as the result type, so that I can return parsing errors as an `Left`. Some test in the REPL:

```
scala> MyJSON.parseFull("[1,2,3]")
res11: Either[MyJSON.NoSuccess,Any] = Right(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))

scala> MyJSON.parseFull("[1,2,3")
res12: Either[MyJSON.NoSuccess,Any] =
Left([1.7] failure: end of input

[1,2,3
      ^)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not work for me with 2.10.0. `JSON.lastNoSuccess` is `null` after parsing bad data.

Comment: Indeed, I can now confirm this. I made a (lengthy) update, please have a look.